# Tag Synonym: Wolfram Programming Cloud

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Wolfram Programming Cloud is now Wolfram Development Platform, see for example [Wolfram Cloud](http://www.wolframcloud.com/). Who can add this synonym to the Wolfram Programming Cloud tag?

Comment: "Wolfram Programming Cloud is now Wolfram Development Platform" No. Wolfram Programming Cloud is now one component of Wolfram Development Platform. http://i.imgur.com/fk619HM.png

Answer (score 5):

I suggest replacing [wolfram-programming-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-programming-cloud) with [wolfram-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-cloud), as the differences between the Development Platform and Mathematica *Online* are neglectable with respect to the Wolfram Language code used within these.

As to how synonyms work the system says:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can **suggest** tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can **vote** for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

Community moderators are able to directly apply synonyms and merges.

Comment: Suggested tag synonyms can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest). Don't forget to vote!